# NodeJS: how to create simple middleware?

Tags: node.js

I'm using NodeJS v6.5.0.
I'm new to it so I'm making some mistakes and would appreciate some help.
I am experimenting with writing my own middleware.
Right now, I have the code working:

```
var http = require('http');

http.createServer(function(req, res) {
    myMiddleware(req, res);
}).listen(3000);

function myMiddleware(req, res) {
    res.end('Hello World');
};
```

However, when I change it to:

```
var http = require('http');

http.createServer(myMiddleware(req, res)).listen(3000);

function myMiddleware(req, res) {
    res.end('Hello World');
};
```

I get the error 'req is not defined'.
Please could someone explain to me why this is happening and what I need to do to fix it?
Cheers.

Comment: This is a JavaScript mistake, it has nothing to do with Node

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just write

```
var http = require('http');

function myMiddleware(req, res) {
    res.end('Hello World');
};

http.createServer(myMiddleware).listen(3000);
```

You need to pass your middleware (the function) to express, not to execute it

Answer (score 0):

We Don't Need to send request or response while using middle ware .

```
var http = require('http');

function myMiddleware() {
      return function(req,res,next) { 
        // do some stuff here 
        next();
      }
  }

http.createServer(myMiddleware).listen(3000);
```

Or if you want to pass parameter in middle ware  you can use in this way

```
  var http = require('http');

    function myMiddleware(getparams) {
          return function(req,res,next) { 
            // do some stuff here 
          console.log(getParams)
            next();
          }
      }

http.createServer(myMiddleware(params)).listen(3000);
```

**Next() is use to pass control to next method or next middle ware .**